# Managing epub filenames in macOS

Tags: books, epub

I have a bunch of ebooks in PDF and epub format on my Mac.  I also have a reMarkable tablet that I would like to use as my e-reader.

Importing the books is easy, the trouble is that the filenames of epubs on the Mac bear no resemblance at all to the name of the book as displayed in iBooks.

For example:

```
Title in Books:  "A Great Book"
Author in Books:  "Some Author"
Filename on macOS Mojave:  9E856035F6F5F129B103BD7A61D3CE72.epub
```

This makes it very hard to drag & drop the files from the mac onto rM and Books won't allow me to drag out of it and onto rM (or maybe rM won't accept it).

Is there any way to get the macOS filenames of epubs, to reflect the information in Books?  PDFs don't have this issue, just the epubs.

Comment: Have you looked into "Calibre?" It is a Mac/PC/Linux ebook manager, editor, creator, reader. The metadata like that is easily editible in Calibre.

Comment: Yes I neglected to mention, some of them were converted by me with calibre, some were downloaded as epubs originally.  Seems to make no difference, none will be accepted by the rm software.

Comment: Have you asked rm support about the problem?

Comment: In general I would manage things in calibre and export from there and not iBooks - iBooks doesn't combine well with non Apple apps. ie look at calibre and rm and ignore Books for the time being

Comment: @TomGewecke No not yet, probably not technically a rm issue so wanted to start elsewhere.

Comment: @mmmmmm Yeah I really don't want to have to re-export things from calibre again since they have already been imported to Books.  This is turning out to be quite a PITA.  And rm is just gonna turn them back into PDFs anyway so... not quite sure at the moment that rm is going to be worthwhile as an e-reader after all.

Comment: Unfortunately unless you stick to one app range you will have to do a reimport - e.g. All in Kindle or Kobo or Books where the app and hardware and book store are all the same company. Otherwise book store to calibre and calibre to each device separately

Comment: Where do these files are located?  Books purchased from Apple located in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books` and have unique identifiers as names. However, imported epubs and pdf should be located in `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud\~com\~apple\~iBooks/Documents` (if syncing over iCloud between devices is enabled). This location is not accessible from Finder, you should use terminal and prepend `open`- this will open this directory in Finder where files should have 'normal' names (or at least I do in Big Sur :-)).

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Thanks, that location is actually perfectly accessible from the Finder as long as ~/Library is visible, or you use the "Goto Location" feature.  Regardless however, my Mobile Documents directory is empty. I've been working with the files in /Containers/ but that's what prompted this post in the first place so... no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: I misunderstood 'importing the books is easy'. I wrongly assumed that these are files obtained outside of Apple bookstore. The books in 'Container' should be books bought from Apple and have unique identifiers as filenames. As of access from Finder to iCloud books: I used goto but ended up in iCloud Documents folder instead of books. However, after I used terminal to open the destination folder I was able to access it from Finder as well.

Comment: Sorry but no, none of these were obtained through the Apple Bookstore.  That's just where they go when I import into Apple Books.  They were originally imported with iBooks years ago, maybe that has something to do with it?